# Pages for each entry from an entry type?

Tags: url, entry-type

Let's say I have an entry type named "Designers", and I have:

- A title field "Full Name"
- A categories field "Specialty"
- Another categories field "Location"

Now I want each designer (that is, each entry) from the "Designers" entry type to link to a another page showing blog entries on which this designer's work is featured.

I'm sorry if I'm not being clear enough... Basically, it's a basic directory what I want to build. People can find designers by specialty and location (not sure if categories is the right way to do it...any suggestions?).

My question is how can I create that page showing the entries. Maybe this can't be done with entry types and I need a separated channel?!

Comment: Rafael, is it right that you want to accomplish this all with a Craft personal license? Because that's what I read between the lines...

Comment: Yup, thanks for the explanation! I'm thinking maybe it's possible to do something like this: visualcache.com/features/by/

Answer (score 3):

What about using a [category group](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/categories) for your designers as well?

Add your "Specialty" and "Locations" category fields to a "Designers" category's field layout and then use a "Designers" category field on your blog entries to assign the designer.

*Sorry for the confusion with my other answer, after re-reading your question today I noticed that I headed in the wrong direction. A "Designers" category would probably be the right way to do it, even if you had the ability to add a second channel section.*

Comment: Ahhhh, why do I tend to over complicate things? :P I guess using a category group for "designers" is exactly right for what I was thinking, carlcs! Just not sure how the code for the category's field layout would be like, hmmm... docs here I come...

Answer (score 1):

You could indeed use entry types to separate your "Designer" and "Blog" entries, but that wouldn't be a very good way to do it. The type of content is just too different to make them a good fit for a single channel section.

But let's try it anyways:

Basically you'd need to [relate](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/relations) the entries, each "Designer" entry with all linked "Blog" entries. To make such relations possible, you add an [entries field](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/entries-fields) "Designer" to the "Blog" entry type. Entries fields can be configured to only show entries of select sections. With a separate "Designers" section you could nicely filter the entries available. If you have one combined channel, where you mix "Designer" and "Blog" entries – even if they are in separate entry types – you will always have them next to each other in your entries field modal.

The ability to further filter the sources available on an entries field other than a filter on the section will [most likely](https://plus.google.com/112173526450245116573/posts/2NHbdQTsKiL) come with an update to Craft though.

But besides this (current) problem, you could definitely mis-use that one single channel for your design. Another thing to mention here, it'd probably be a bit more of work to set this all up.